# Building Python from the source as 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, build

> I am assuming Python X.X (my case 3.8) has not yet been released and is therfore not compiled to download, and if I want to run a x64 bit version I need to compile it for myself.

I have Visual Studio Express installed and have tried to build Python from the source.  So far I did this:

- Downloaded the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython)
- run `cpython\PCbuild\build.bat` as suggested [in the documentation](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#windows) (I see nothing saying how to build x64 bit)
- Waited

When the build finishes I run `python.exe` and I get this:

```
Python 3.8.0a0 (heads/master:cac4fef886, Jun 16 2018, 12:39:58) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

This Python is a x32 bit (due to `v.1914 32 bit (Intel)`)

I looked in `SpecialBuilds.txt` and no luck there either.

How do I build Python as x64 bit?

Comment: `build.bat -p x64`. Run `build.bat -h` to list the options. The readme [explains this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PCbuild/readme.txt#L57). The devguide told you to read it.

Comment: @eryksun  That was easier than I thought.  How did I not find it?  Could you please consider leaving an answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but I think you should delete the question. This is a straight path from the devguide to the readme to the section on using build.bat to listing the options with `build -h`, which clearly shows how to target x64. If we have questions and answers for every straight path through a documented process, we'll drown in the noise of billions of questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
build.bat -p x64
```

Run `build.bat -h` to list the options.

The `README` [explains this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PCbuild/readme.txt#L57). The devguide told you to read it.

<sub>*- Answer in comments given by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)*</sub>